# Prints every 10 elements in the array with 100 elements many times

Tags: java, arrays

i just created an array have 100 elements, so now i want get 10 elements print first, secondly i want continuing 10 elements print out, and 10 elements third keep going. My code is below:

```
    int[] array = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,..., 100 };
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        count++;
        if (count == 10) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ultimately you want to print all the elements?

Comment: What is your question? If you don't get the output you want and are asking why, please post the actual output and the desired output.

Comment: Do you want to only print every 10th element, or all 100 elements, 10 on each row?

Comment: Please clarify you question, You explanation is not enough to understand the question and answer it@John.D

Comment: Can you include some sample input or output for our understanding ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is correct, only issue is with the printing of array values.

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,....,100};
     int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            count++;
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
            if (count == 10) {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: A more elegant solution would be using the modula-operator insteand of resetting to zero: `if (count % 10 == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily by iterating through the array with a double for-loop.
One loop will iterate through the modulo index and the other will print the 10 elements with that modulo value.

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,100};
for (int offset = 0; offset < array.length/10; offset++)
    for (int i = 0 + offset; i < array.length; i+= array.length/10)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
```